# CSS only: moving nested content into side drawer

Tags: html, css

Anyone know of any tricks to get the main content to move left ([in my example](http://jsfiddle.net/bns0kdmo/)) so it is lined up with the right drawer. I'm sure it has something to do with getting the absolute drawer outside of the overflow:hidden wrapper.

Here's the html, the css is in the [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bns0kdmo/):

```
<nav>
    <div class="header">
        Title
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <ul>
            <li>pizza</li>
            <li>tacos</li>
            <li>nachos</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<main>
    <header class="rightnav">
        <span class="left-nav">
            toggle
        </span>
        <span class="content">
            <input/>
            link1 link2 link3
        </span>
        <span class="right-nav">
            icon
        </span>
     </header>
     <article>
        <div class="header">header</div>
        <div class="content">content</div>
     </article>
     <article>
        <div class="header">header2</div>
        <div class="content">content2</div>
     </article>
     <article class="detail">
        <div class="header">header3</div>
        <div class="content">content3</div>
     </article>
</main>
```

I know it can be done if I break the right drawer outside of the main wrapper, just wondering if there are any techniques to get it to work leaving the html as is.

Comment: Your question is very ambiguous. What are you defining as the "Main Content"? What do you mean by "lined up?" And for that matter, what are you describing as the "right drawer?" Perhaps putting some content in each section in the fiddle to explain what each does would help.

And you will definitely need to clarify what is supposed to "line up" with what, and what you mean by that.

Comment: Main content = `<main>content in here</main>`. Right drawer is purple vertical column with the css class `rightnav`. Basically, I'm looking to get the `main header .content` to display as a vertical column (in purple) when the `rightnav` is used. When the `rightnav` is not given, the main->header->span.content will show up in the top nav (blue). So even simpler, I'm looking for a way to pull an absolute div, contained inside of an `overflow:hidden` wrapper, outside of the wrapper.